# Identify a client disconnected from a Socket in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost

I have a C++ Server where Clients would connect to the Server socket and fetch Search results. I am using Boost library for my Socket programming.

There will be 5 search results in all for which a Client connects. These Search results are expensive for the Server to compute and the computation is done in an iterative way. Now what happens many times is that the clients disconnect after they have received the results for 2 or 3 Search results. I want to stop the Search processing thread as soon as the client who made the request disconnects. What is the best API call to confirm that ? I am willing to write my own wrapper on top of boost if this is even possible.

I am using HTTP only.

thanks

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS (or both) as your protocol?

Comment: @owacoder : I added the info to the question. I am using HTTP only.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can detect a TCP disconnect is by doing I/O to it. After some sends to a peer which has disconnected you will get ECONNRESET. This won't happen on the first send due to TCP buffering.

Comment: Thanks for the information but in such a scenario I would actually end up sending a rogue message to the Client ?

Comment: @Geek, as far as I know, the most common way to handle these things with HTTP(S) is to use connection timeout monitoring (disconnecting the socket if no activity occurred within a certain timeframe). Timeouts for request reception are often shorter than timeouts for request handling (i.e., in my [facil.io](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools) project, the default incoming http timeout is 5 seconds, while response handling times out at 300 seconds).